# API Rails: How to render a model's custom attribute in a controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a #index action in my controller, I'm rendering the model as below. Though, I would like to include a custom attribute but it's never rendered, how can I do that?

```
class MyModel < ApplicationRecord
  def custom_attr
    attr1 + attr2
  end
end
```

```
class MyModelsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    # 'custom-attr' is not rendered.
    render json: MyModel.all, status: :ok, only: %i[attr1, attr2, custom_attr]
  end
end
```

Comment: Look into gems like `blueprinter`, the added serialization layer makes things like that much easier to do.

Answer (score 2):

Thats not an attribute. Its just an instance method. `attributes` are really a Rails specific feature of models that is really a setter/getter coupled with metadata.

```
class Person
  include ActiveModel::Model
  include ActiveModel::Attributes
  attribute :name
  attribute :age
end

irb(main):009:0> Person.new.attributes
=> {"name"=>nil, "age"=>nil, "birthplace"=>nil}
```

When you render an model as JSON rails use [`#as_json`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html#method-i-as_json) which calls `#serializeable_hash` on the model. This serializes the attributes based on the attributes method. This is where the options are actually passed.

As `#custom_attr` is not actually an attribute its of course not included in the serialization.

You can solve this by:

- Override `#as_json` on the model to customize its serialization.
- Use a serializer layer such as ActiveModel::Serializers or JBuilder to customize the JSON representation of the model. (recommended)

Comment: I see, can't I have a computed attribute in my model that is not stored in DB?

Comment: I get it, thanks. :-) though, in my example, how would you make it read-only and computed?

Comment: The easiest way to do this would be to just use `MyModel.select("*", "CONCAT('attr', ' ', 'attr2') AS custom_attr")`. Rails will automatically turn any columns in the result set into attributes. The right way is to use a serialization layer instead.

Comment: I just want to have a read-only attribute that is calculated, like the example I gave. I don't understand why I am struggling to find what appears to be a basic thing in my opinion. ^^ I don't want to write custom SQL, I need to compute them in Ruby;

Comment: I'm not sure ActiveModel::Model actually has read-only attributes (ActiveRecord does). Everything seems basic when you have no clue about the complexity involved.

Comment: ActiveModel::Serializers is not maintained anymore, they list some alternatives themselves here https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers#status-of-ams